# textBox1.Tag equivalent in Web Forms?

Tags: c#, webforms

What is the equivalent to textBox1.Tag in Webforms?

Comment: Could you not just put the item in the session?

Answer (score 1):

Inherit from the base control and add a strongly-typed property.

Comment: as a beginner facing the same problem. Could you please explain a bit more ?